# Using a WITH clause inside SELECT * INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL for which I want to backup the results in to a new table (using SELECT * INTO backup_table)...

```
 WITH LIST AS 
(SELECT column1 
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column1
FROM table2
UNION 
SELECT column1
FROM table3
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT
 a.column1
 a.column2
 a.column3
FROM table2 a
WHERE a.column6 NOT IN (SELECT field1 FROM LIST)
AND a.column3 ='1'
ORDER BY a.column3
```

So far I have tried this but get an error:

```
SELECT * INTO backup_table FROM (    
 WITH LIST AS 
(SELECT column1 
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column1
FROM table2
UNION 
SELECT column1
FROM table3
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT
 a.column1
 a.column2
 a.column3
FROM table2 a
WHERE a.column6 NOT IN (SELECT field1 FROM LIST)
AND a.column3 ='1'
ORDER BY a.column3) a
```

The errors I get are:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
> common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
> context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
> semicolon.
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'

I'm using SQL Server 2014 (12.0.6433.1)

Comment: When you using sql server, why did you not add an aappropiate tag?

Comment: `with`, similar to a *view* or a *derived table* defines a table *expression* - it is defined at the start of your query and then referenced, you don't define it within a `select`; create your backup table first, then use *that* in your main query.

Comment: The `SELECT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`/etc statement goes *after* the `WITH` not *before* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ;WITH LIST AS 
(SELECT column1 
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column1
FROM table2
UNION 
SELECT column1
FROM table3
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT
 a.column1
 a.column2
 a.column3
INTO backup_table
FROM table2 a
WHERE a.column6 NOT IN (SELECT field1 FROM LIST)
AND a.column3 ='1'
ORDER BY a.column3
```

Comment: Shouldn't even need the sub-query. Just `WITH x AS (foo) SELECT a, b, c INTO y FROM x WHERE bar`. Also, `ORDER BY` with `SELECT INTO` is redundant unless using `TOP`, etc.

Comment: HI @Dordi Thanks. I'm still getting an error though. "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

Comment: @Matt, you should add a semicolon `;` before `WITH`, i think you have another statement before `WITH`, that's why you need to add a semicolon  `;`